# How to jwt creation with node.js javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I need to create a JWT(Json Web Token) , I have client credentials token in ES256 algorithm.

Requirement - > https://docs.talkdesk.com/docs/using-a-signed-jwt

SO I have Install Nodejs in local , when I am trying to get this work its giving me error, I am new to javascript. may anyone please help me to get it work.

Error is internal/crypto/sig.js80

```
 const http = require('http');
 var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
 var uuid = require('uuid/v4');

//create a server object:

var private_key = 'private_key goes here'
 private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" + private_key + "\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"

var header = {
  kid: 'bdef4554463d8078be9af1d9de55'
}

var payload = {
  iss: 'a57bb14a44455e98800d6a513953fc0',
  sub: 'a57bb14a445541e98800d6a513953fc0',
  aud: 'https://c2performdev.talkdeskid.com/oauth/token',
  jti: uuid(),
  exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 300,
 iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
}

 token = jwt.sign(payload, private_key, {header: header, algorithm: 'ES256'})
```

Answer (score 6):

There is issue with the key. The same code works fine if key is ok.

```
var fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var uuid = require("uuid/v4");

//create a server object:

var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

var private_key = fs.readFileSync("./private.pem");
var header = {
  kid: "bdef4554463d8078be9af1d9de55"
};

var payload = {
  iss: "a57bb14a44455e98800d6a513953fc0",
  sub: "a57bb14a445541e98800d6a513953fc0",
  aud: "https://c2performdev.talkdeskid.com/oauth/token",
  jti: uuid(),
  exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 300,
  iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
};

token = jwt.sign(payload, private_key, { header: header, algorithm: "ES256" });

console.log(token);
```

I following command to generate key in mac.

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -noout -out private.pem
openssl ec -in private.pem -pubout -out public.pem
```

the body is key file is as follows.

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEICu0QorVDVCvfc9JeiDlUxK4IJnx69vxOwLYZsPtVcmToAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEQi9ENvV3eiN/hVed5eBqOTUa5v+olsdHk51RZbJNT7Rwz42tNSMrzucr
Jhn7xIOvQgw0NH5Tad+BE7ybIakSUg==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

this does not match what you have done. Try correcting the key structure.

Comment: Many thanks for you reply , the key given in question is not correct , as I have changed them for security , and I am using windows terminal , the token we are received from talkdesk https://docs.talkdesk.com/docs/using-a-signed-jwt , I need to create a JWT token to get it work